# Weird text-formatting after upgrade to 2.7.0

Tags: mysql, text-formatting, textarea

I upgraded a site today from 2.5.5 to 2.7.0. Everything went well except from one ting:

When outputting textareas with text formatting none EE will insert paragraphs and whitespaces - expected behaviour is for EE to do nothing. I wonder what the cause could be?

For example this in the database:

```
<p>Der er 18 åbne afstemninger, og du kan samtidig seriøst overveje at komme med dit input til debatopslagene i Fri Debat (som stadig er ekstremt meget i beta!)</p>

                    <p>Nyhedsbrevet udsendes ikke hver uge henover sommeren.</p>
```

will be rendered like this:

```
<p>Der er 18 åbne afstemninger, og du kan samtidig seriøst overveje at komme med dit input til debatopslagene i Fri Debat (som stadig er ekstremt meget i beta!)</p><p>&nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  <br /></p><p>Nyhedsbrevet udsendes ikke hver uge henover sommeren.</p>
```

even though formatting is **none**. So both p, br and whitespace added.

Help *much* appreciated!

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You said that is what is in the database?  It sounds like that is what is stored, so that is what is outputting. Can you post a screenshot of your actual textarea field with content in it? And it's just a plain, standard 'textarea'?

Comment: I just added the screenshot. What happens is that each time there is a empty line, EE outputs p tags with whitespaces which is not what should happen and not what used to happen with "none" formatting.

Comment: Ok, very strange, but I noticed that I couldn't change **Allow override on publish page?** for the field in question. It always reverts back to No (and still does).

However, it is now working again after I changed default from XHTML to none. So, now it's working for none - but probably not for anything else, because it won't allow me to change the settings on Publish page; at least it doesn't respect the changes.